# Where do I ask this question related to piracy?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I wish to ask this question-
Why do crackers/rippers do what they do(cracking apps/games, ripping movies etc)...what do they gain by doing so?
Where do I ask it?

Comment: On a forum in a chatroom, I'd say. In it's current form it is not a good question for the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: If polished up, it'd be a psychology or economy question, not a programming question. I'd start with looking at [gift economy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_economy) if you wanted to figure out motivations; status through generous contribution.

Comment: It's basically [this](http://www.quora.com/Movie-Piracy/What-motivates-piracy-groups-to-film-rip-movies-and-upload-them-to-the-internet) question. However since the Stack Exchange is a vast network of users...I thought that I would get a better insight into the motivation behind piracy.

Comment: Yes, and the top answer basically describes the motivation as: gift economy. I give something, I get stuff in return. This is a psychology question, cognitive science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those are questions related to executables binary format, reverse engineering, interceptings call withing game code etc., as well as specific programming problems you've met while doing so (for example, converting the format of the video) it's **StackOverflow**.

Movie ripping seems more like **SuperUser** or **SoftwareRecommendations**.

If you want to reasearch psychological motives for coding for free, **Programmers** or **CognitiveSciences** might welcome your questions (if not so obviously open-ended).

Comment: CognitiveSciences looks like the best option...thanks!